# SqlDependency.Start not working in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple client server application and I got stuck with sql. When i ran code like

```
using System.Data;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password");
    }
}
```

then I see correctly created queues and services in service broker in database on SQL server

but when i ran similar code from unity:

```
using System.Data;
public class ABC : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password")
    }
}
```

then no queues and services are created, and there are no errors in console.

No matter where this code is executed, SqlDependency.Start not working.
I tried to use different versions of system.data.dll but it did not help.

```
bool a=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password")
Debug.Log(a)
```

return true

Please help!

Comment: Did you see the `Debug.Log(a)`? What is your Unity version and where did you get the dll that allowed you to use `System.Data`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using 2018.1.1f1 unity version. I get system.data from Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0, tried various dlls from Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono. I can see Debig.Log(a) and it returns True

Answer (score 0):

ok, I spent two days looking for a solution to this problem and found it.

first go to the Edit > Project Settings > Player. In "Other options" change "Scripting Runtime Version" to ".NET 4.x Equivalent" and "Api Compatibility Level" to ".NET 4x", restart Unity
Next go to the Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5 and copy System.Data.dll to your project folder.

And finally it works!